How to calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}-\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}\right)$?
Let $\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}, \operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)=x^{n}+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+b_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0}$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, how to calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}-\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}\right)$ ?
I can calculate the limit for some small $n$.
For $n=1$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x+a_{0}\right)-\left(x+b_{0}\right)\right)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(a_{0}-b_{0}\right)\\
&=a_{0}-b_{0}
\end{aligned}$$
For $n=2$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}}-\sqrt{x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}}\right)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}\right)-\left(x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}\right)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}}+\sqrt{x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(a_{1}-b_{1}\right)+\frac{a_{0}-b_{0}}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a_{1}}{x}+\frac{a_{0}}{x^{2}}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{b_{1}}{x}+\frac{b_{0}}{x^{2}}}}\\
&=\frac{a_{1}-b_{1}}{2}
\end{aligned}$$
For $n=3$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}}\right)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}\right)-\left(x^{3}+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{3}+a_{2}x^2+a_{1}x+a_{0}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}\right)\left(x^3+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{3}+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}\right)^{2}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(a_{2}-b_{2}\right)+\frac{a_{1}-b_{1}}{x}+\frac{a_{0}-b_{0}}{x^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{a_{2}}{x}+\frac{a_{1}}{x^{2}}+\frac{a_{0}}{x^{3}}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{a_{2}}{x}+\frac{a_{1}}{x^{2}}+\frac{a_{0}}{x^{3}}\right)\left(1+\frac{b_{2}}{x}+\frac{b_{1}}{x^{2}}+\frac{b_{0}}{x^{3}}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{b_{2}}{x}+\frac{b_{1}}{x^{2}}+\frac{b_{0}}{x^{3}}\right)^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{a_{2}-b_{2}}{3}
\end{aligned}$$
However, it is hard to find the limit if $n$ is large. How to calculate the limit for arbitrary $n$ ?

are you allowed to use Taylor expansion?

Observe that $$P_n^{1/n}(x)-Q_n^{1/n}(x)={x^{1-n} [P_n(x)-Q_n(x)]\over \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x^{-n}P_n(x))^{k/n}(x^{-n}Q_n(x))^{(n-1-k)/n}}$$ The expressions $x^{-n}P_n(x)$ and $x^{-n}Q_n(x)$ tend to $1$ while the numerator tends to $a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}.$ Hence we get $(a_{n-1}-b_{n-1})/n.$

$$f(x)=(P_n(x))^{1/n}-(Q_n(x))^{1/n}=x\left((1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{A(1/x)}{x^2})^{1/n}-(1+\frac{b_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{B(1/x}{x^2})^{1/n}\right)$$ where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials in $1/x.$ Therefore $$\lim _{x\to \infty}f(x)=\frac{a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}}{n}.$$

As I already wrote somewhere : one of my old professors used to say (I quote him) :
"We shall always be closer to $0$ than to $\infty$".
So, obeying him, let $x=\frac 1 y$ and work around $y=0$. Take logarithms, use Taylor series, divide by $n$ and re-exponentiate using the fact that
$$\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}=\exp\Bigg(\frac 1n \log\big(P_n(x)\big)  \Bigg)$$ this allows to get the limit and even more such as
$$\frac {a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}} n+\frac {(n-1)(b_{n-1}^2-a_{n-1}^2 )+2n(a_{n-2}-b_{n-2} )}{2\,n^2\,\,x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

what if $a_{i} = b_i = 0$ for $i \in {n-1,n-2}$?

@NN2. What if all $a_i$ and $b_i$ are equal and (even more) equal to $0$. Just kidding, for sure. Cheers :-)

Inspired by Claude Leibovici, I found a generic solution to such limits: the Laurent series expansion.
To calculate the Laurent series of $\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}$ at $x=\infty$, let $y=\frac{1}{x}$, and calculate the Taylor series of $\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(y)}$ at $y=0$
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(y)}&=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{y^{n}}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{y^{n-1}}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{y^{n-2}}+\cdots+\frac{a_{1}}{y}+a_{0}}\\
&=\frac{1}{y}\sqrt[n]{1+a_{n-1}y+a_{n-2}y^{2}+\cdots+a_{1}y^{n-1}+a_{0}y^{n}}\\
&=\frac{1}{y}\left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}y+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(y^{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}(y)
\end{aligned}$$
Substitute $x$ back and the Laurent series of $\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}$ at $x=\infty$ is
$$\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}=x+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
Similarly the Laurent series of $\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}$ at $x=\infty$ is
$$\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}=x+\frac{b_{n-1}}{n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
So the limit is
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{n}}}(x)}-\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}\right)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-\left(x+\frac{b_{n-1}}{n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}}{n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}}{n}}
\end{aligned}$$
We can also get a stronger proposition with the above conclusion:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[m]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{m}}}(x)}-\sqrt[n]{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}\right)=\boxed{\frac{a_{m-1}}{m}-\frac{b_{n-1}}{n}}
$$
where $m, n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

A more general question: Let $\operatorname{\mathit{P_m}}(x)=x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$, $\operatorname{\mathit{Q_n}}(x)=x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0}$, $\operatorname{\mathit{R_k}}(x)=x^k+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots+c_{1}x+c_{0}$, $\operatorname{\mathit{S_l}}(x)=x^l+d_{l-1}x^{l-1}+\cdots+d_{1}x+d_{0}$ where $m, n, k, l\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \land m>n, k>l$, calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[m-n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{m}}}(x)/\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}-\sqrt[k-l]{\operatorname{\mathit{R_{k}}}(x)/\operatorname{\mathit{S_{l}}}(x)}\right)$.
Similarly, the Laurent series of $\sqrt[m-n]{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{m}}}(x)/\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}$ and $\sqrt[k-l]{\operatorname{\mathit{R_{k}}}(x)/\operatorname{\mathit{S_{l}}}(x)}$ at $x=\infty$ are
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt[m-n]{\frac{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{m}}}(x)}{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}}&=x+\frac{a_{m-1}-b_{n-1}}{m-n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
\sqrt[k-l]{\frac{\operatorname{\mathit{R_{k}}}(x)}{\operatorname{\mathit{S_{l}}}(x)}}&=x+\frac{c_{k-1}-d_{l-1}}{k-l}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
So the limit is
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[m-n]{\frac{\operatorname{\mathit{P_{m}}}(x)}{\operatorname{\mathit{Q_{n}}}(x)}}-\sqrt[k-l]{\frac{\operatorname{\mathit{R_{k}}}(x)}{\operatorname{\mathit{S_{l}}}(x)}}\right)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x+\frac{a_{m-1}-b_{n-1}}{m-n}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-\left(x+\frac{c_{k-1}-d_{l-1}}{k-l}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_{m-1}-b_{n-1}}{m-n}-\frac{c_{k-1}-d_{l-1}}{k-l}+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{a_{m-1}-b_{n-1}}{m-n}-\frac{c_{k-1}-d_{l-1}}{k-l}}
\end{aligned}$$
